# Django - filtering on related model custom queries

Tags: django, django-models

I have three models: `Player`, `League`, and `LeaguePlayer`. `LeaguePlayer` has a foreign key relationship with `Player` and a foreign key relationship to `League`. `Player` has several custom queries, for example:

`Player.objects.by_position('catcher')`, or

`Player.objects.by_position(position='batter', exclude='catcher')`, or

`Player.objects.by_best_position('shortstop')`.

I would like to be able to use the `Player` custom queries when I am filtering against `LeaguePlayer`. An example might be: `LeaguePlayer.objects.by_position('catcher')`, which would use the `Player` custom filter `by_position`. So if `LeaguePlayer` has a field `player_value`, I would like to do something like:

`LeaguePlayer.objects.by_position('catcher').filter('player_value__gt'=100)`

If there isn't a way to somehow 'inherit' the filters from `Player` for `LeaguePlayer`? Or if not, is there a different way to organize my models so this type of filtering might be easy to create?

@yuvi, some code behind my question:

```
from django.db import models
from model_utils.managers import PassThroughManager
from player.models import Positions

class League(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(verbose_name="League name", max_length=50, unique=True)
    number_of_teams = models.IntegerField(
        verbose_name="Number of teams in your league",
        choices=[(i, i) for i in range(6, 19)],
        blank=False, default=10
    )
    ...

class PlayerQuerySet(models.query.QuerySet):
    def exclude_position(self, exclude=None):
        non_excluded_positions = [...]
        return self.filter(all_positions__in=non_excluded_positions).distinct()

    def by_position(self, positions=None, exclude=None):
        player_set = self
        if exclude is not None:
            player_set = self.exclude_position(exclude)

        if positions is None:
            return player_set.distinct()

        return player_set.filter(all_positions__in=positions).distinct()

class PlayersManager(PassThroughManager):
    def get_query_set(self):
        return PlayerQuerySet(self.model, using=self._db)

class Players(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    primary_position = models.ForeignKey(Positions, related_name='primary')
    all_positions = models.ManyToManyField(Positions, related_name='positions')

    objects = PlayersManager()

class LeaguePlayerQuerySet(models.query.QuerySet):
    def custom_query(self):
        return some filtered version of self

class LeaguePlayerManager(PassThroughManager):
    def get_query_set(self):
        return LeaguePlayerQuerySet(self.model, using=self._db)

class LeaguePlayer(models.Model):
    league = models.ForeignKey(League)
    player = models.ForeignKey(Players)
    player_value_property = models.FloatField(null=True)
    ...

    objects = LeaguePlayerManager()

    @property
    def player_value(self):
        if not self.player_value_property:
            self.player_value_property = calculate value based on self.league and self.player
            self.save()
        return self.player_value_property
```

Details on PassThroughManager can be found here: https://bitbucket.org/carljm/django-model-utils/overview. In short, it allows for the chaining of custom QuerySet methods.

Comment: What do you mean by custom queries? raw SQL or methods?

Comment: @yuvi Methods against `models.query.QuerySet`

Comment: You subclassed QuerySet and added custom methods I take it? Could you perhaps share some of it (or the general idea at least)? Also - the duplicate ForeignKey and your models names suggest you're looking for creating a ManyToMany 'through' relationship am I right? (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#intermediary-manytomany)

Comment: @yuvi You are correct about subclassing QuerySet. I have thought about adding a `players` field to `League` and then using a through relationship. It does not seem to make sense, however, to add a `leagues` field to `Player`and through relationship that way. Perhaps I'm overthinking this. Technically, `LeaguePlayer` doesn't need to be a model, but rather, a simple python class, holding methods which use both `Player` and `League` as inputs. I set up `LeaguePlayer` to use the QuerySet APIs mainly, and secondarily to save some of the calculated values into specific `LeaguePlayer` fields.

Comment: That is a possibility. Can you perhaps share you entire models.py and your Subclass QuerySet so I could try and help you? I can't tell you if you're really overthinking it on a theroetical level just by looking at your queries

Comment: @yuvi actual code provided above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of the trouble I see with your code is your DB design, which is wayyyy too complex and confusing, and there is a lot of cleanup to do. **good db design means easy and logical querying**. The subclassing of the QuerySet looks like overkill to me, but that part makes sense and is written pretty well

so short answer:

Use LeaguePlayer as an intermediary table between Player and League and move the player_value property to Player:

```
class Player(models.Model):
    league = models.ManyToManyField(League, through='LeaguePlayer')

    @property
    def player_value(self): 
        return ( 'calculation based on self.league and self' )
```

<sub>probably better to name it value because you're already referencing a player object</sub>

then the query looks like the others without changing a thing:

```
Player.objects.by_position('catcher').filter('player_value__gt'=100)
```

long answer:

1. if LeaguePlayer does not contain any more information, I see no reason to keep it at all. Even without the 'through' it still functions as an intermediary table between Player and League, but one that has an unnecessary field, and a property which is a calculation (which populates that same field). If that's all it does, just remove it completely.
2. change all model names from plural to single. That is the (sensible) convention
3. You shouldn't link Player to Position twice. It seems to make more sense to link it once and find some way to recognize primary positions as a method (either using a another intermediary table or using a boolean field called 'primary' for position. I dunno, whatever makes sense to you).

With these changes in mind, the Player model should look a little like this:

```
class Player(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    positions = models.ManyToManyField(Position)
    league = models.ManyToManyField(League)

    def primary_position(self):
        return self.positions.all().filter(primary=True)

    @property
    def player_value(self): 
        return ( 'calculation based on self.league and self' )
```

Hope this helps, good luck!

p.s. Remember, calculations should not be saved in the database. That's what methods are for

Comment: Thanks for this type of reply, which really thinks about what the problem really is rather than how to solve for something which might not be necessary. I want to think more about this because I'm sure I will have some questions. Some notes. The properties which I have saved are expensive calculations, and I want to be able to filter on those values. So the unnecessary table gains me QuerySet APIs against property values, which is very valuable. Also, I can bulk_create in LeaguePlayer, while running those calculations, which adds to efficiency.

Comment: When dealing with calculations, the most efficient way is to translate it to an aggregate function or raw SQL. However, there should be something to say in favor of the list comprehension way of doing things `[obj.my_method() for obj in objects]`. I have used such filtering in my own projects and even with large and complex DBs the efficiency was surprisingly better than I expected, and it also makes for a much more readable code. As for LeaguePlayer, I think having an accessible bulk_create probably doesn't justify having another unnecessary table

Comment: One of reasons why I have custom methods on QuerySets is so I can filter by properties. These properties can be set up as @cached_property so the calculation only occurs once. Of course, the result of those queries is a list and not a QuerySet. I can continue this structure which would be much like you describe. I find that the ability to extend the QuerySet API really simplifies code writing and reading, excepting the part about setting up the custom methods against the QuerySet. Any further thoughts about queries against model properties? That very desirable feature is what lead to this.

Comment: Only that in my experience I always used methods and never had to resort to model properties. I found that the most efficient thing you could do is have a neatly ordered and pre planned db design. Relationships (i.e FK and m2m), if not tightly constructed, can end up costing a lot more than a "non-efficient" list comprehension

Answer (score 1):

How about something like

```
catchers = Player.objects.by_position('catcher').values_list('id', flat = True)
leagueCatchers = LeaguePlayer.objects.filter(player__in = catchers).filter('player_value__gt'=100)
```

Comment: if I am going to write custom queries for `LeaguePlayer`, I will use approaches like this. It would seem somehow djangoistic that I could arrange things so I wouldn't need to mirror the custom queries against a related model in such a manner.